# How to count all letters that have been inputted into a program

Tags: java, string

I'm making a program for my computer science class that needs to follow these instructions : Write a Java program that asks the user to input characters from the command line.  Input will continue until the period (.) character is input alone, followed by “Enter”.  At the end of the program, output the total number of characters (counting the period) that were input. 
For example:

```
Hello 
t 
h 
e 
r 
e 
. 
Number of characters: 11
```

This is what i have for code

```
String input;    //declares variables
int count,length;

input = "";

System.out.println("Enter letters");

 do {

    input = stdin.readLine();
    length = input.length();

    }
    while (!input.equals("."));


System.out.println("the total amount of character is " + length);
```

Comment: Change `length = input.length();` to `length += input.length();` You need `+=` to add newest length value to existing length.

Comment: Thank you!!!!! it works now!!

Comment: Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter letters");// Input  "Udara.Kasun.java"
    String InputLetters = scanner.next();
 
 System.out.println("the total amount of character is s: "+InputLetters.length());
  
    String MatchWord = ".";

 System.out.println(InputLetters.indexOf(MatchWord)); // prints "5"
 System.out.println(InputLetters.lastIndexOf(MatchWord)); // prints "12"